# Credit card balance is not updating if we use Paypal's Guest Check out feature

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal Website Payments Standard for implementing Donation button in our application.
I have added Guest check out feature to give flexibility to the Users to Donate even if they Donot wish to have a Paypal Account.

For testing purpose in sandbox, I tried donating via guest check out option by using one of the preconfigured paypal's account, by using its credit card information.
The donated amount is reflected in the statements of the receiver.
But the amount is not debitted from the Donor's paypal balance..
Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

I need to test the guest check -out feature and see the amount debitted from the account.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If donor is using a credit card it would not affect the PayPal balance. Credit card is a funding source on the account but shouldn't be tied to the account balance because theoretically it is a line of credit.